# I can't connect my share folder

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I can't connect my share folder as same issue.

My home server is running Windows Server 2008 R2. I've had it running for almost a year now without any issues with shared folders. This past week I had an issue with my modem which required it to be power cycled and with that I power cycled my router.

After that I haven't been able to connect to my shared network folders. I have no idea why that would even cause an issue as I've power cycled my networking equipment in the past without issues and none of my settings appear to have been lost.

I am mapping these drives on my Windows 7 Ultimate machine using "Map Network Drive", from there I enter \SERVER\Storage as I'm trying to connect to my shared folder named Storage.

I receive the following error every time I try mapping the drive:

> Windows cannot access \Server\Storage
>
> Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise there might be a problem
>   with your network. To try to identify and resolve network problems,
>   click Diagnose.
>
> Details: Error code: 0x80070035 The network path was not found.

When I click Diagnose I get the following:

> Problems found
>
> file and print sharing resource (SERVER) is online but isn't
>   responding to connection attempts.
>
> The remote computer isn't responding to connection on port 445,
>   possibly due to firewall or security policy settings, or because it
>   might be temporarily unavailable. Windows couldn't find any problems
>   with the firewall on your computer.

I've tried this from multiple computers with the same issue too.

To resolve the problems so far I've tried:

```
Disabling the firewall on SERVER
Modifying NetBT\Parameters registry values
Recreating the shared folders
Checking and rechecking the shared folder permissions.
Resetting my user account password on the server used to access the shared folder.
```

Comment: Is your modem your network's DHCP server too?

Comment: This^^^ and a question: Does it work if you use the server's IP instead of the name?

Comment: No its not working with ip also